# Python how to do find with leading and trailing spaces

Tags: python, find, space

I'm doing an extensive word search. How do I do a find that keeps leading and trailing spaces.
the word is imported from a list.

An example:

find " oil " in "Use Cooking Oil"

but
do not find with "Sally spoiled the food."

`.find()` strips the leading and trailing spaces.
nltk tokenizing does also.

this code works if i want a simple lookup. It finds "oil" in "spoiled" which, for me, creates a false positive. the false positive is what I am trying to solve. I've tried putting " oil " in the word list (with spaces), but all methods I've tried strip the leading spaces (" oil " becomes "oil").

```
for r in search_list_df['title']:     ###<- Search for word in this list.
    tfl_converted = []
    token_found_list.clear()

    words = search_list                ###<- list of words to cycle through. (including " oil ")
    for x in words:
        phrase = x
        text = r

        if phrase in r:            ### <- this works if i DO NOT care about leading spaces.
            token_found_list.append(x)
            tfl_converted = ", ".join(token_found_list)
    if len(token_found_list) > 0: 
        search_list_output.append(tfl_converted)
    else:
        tfl_converted = float("nan")
        search_list_output.append(tfl_converted)
```

How do I iterate through a list of words and keep the leading and trailing spaces to avoid false positives and find only exact word matches?

Answer (score 0):

You could split the sentence into an array of words. This way, you can see if a word is present in the array, and thus overcome false positives:

```py
words = [word.lower() for word in sentence.split()]
if 'oil' in words:
    print(True)
```

Here, I have also made sure that every word in the sentence is lowercase, such that case sensitivity is not going to be a problem. The split() method makes sure that the string `sentence` is split by spaces.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you both! I don't know why I didn't think of either answer. Both are so simple and elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function `find_term` with oneliner,

```
def find_term(sentence, term):
    return len([word for word in sentence.lower().split() if term == word]) > 0
```

then you can use it in your code like,

```
sentence = " xy z Oil spoil"

if find_term(sentence, "oil"):
  #do something with the sentence
```